# Can someone help me install WineHQ?

Tags: apt, package-management, wine, dpkg, dependencies

I wanted to install wine in Ubuntu 20.04, but I did all the way like in official instruction [here](https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu)...

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
wget -nc https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key
sudo apt-key add winehq.key
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ focal main' 
sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable
```

but then this error message appears in the terminal:

```
sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 winehq-stable : Depends: wine-stable (= 6.0.1~hirsute-1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Purge the ppa and install the version from the repos unless you have a specific need for a newer version of wine. Currently `wine-stable` is version 3.0.1ubuntu1

Comment: I installed Linux for the first time literary 3 hours ago. So can you please tell me how to purge ppa and what is that ppa?

Comment: I found this how to solve my problem:
sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer [here](https://losst.ru/ustanovka-wine-v-ubuntu-18-04).

The answer to my question is:

```
sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable
```